# How list all package in a specific jar file?

Tags: java, jar, package

How can I get all package names in a specific jar file from within Java?

I know find how to get all classes in a jar, but how do I get only package names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the packages defined in a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744536/how-do-i-find-the-packages-defined-in-a-jar)

Comment: I need do it inside a java application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do this in java code then you can use [`JarFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html).

List all classes from given jar and from that get all packages (by extracting its package from full name).

```java
JarFile jar = ... \\ create from file

jar.stream()
    .map(ZipEntry::getName)
    .filter(name -> name.endsWith(".class"))
    .map(name -> name
        .substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('/'))
        .replace('/', '.')
    )
    .distinct()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `replace('/', '.')` is faster than replaceAll, since it doesn’t use a regular expression.